# 'this' keyword not being reassigned by function.prototype.call

Tags: javascript, object, this

consider this module:

```
//Adder component
(function init() {

//Initilize variables
const addButton = document.getElementById('add-btn');
const userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');
const userOutput = document.getElementById('user-output');

const App = {
    //Register event handlers
    registerHandlers() {
        addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.addKeyValue.call(App, userInput.value);
        });
    },

    addKeyValue(input) {
        userOutput.value = input;
    },

};

App.registerHandlers();

})();
```

When the click event is fired this fails because `this.addKeyValue` is undefined because at the run time of that function `this` is referring to the input element and not the `App` object. But isn't that what the `Function.prototype.call` function is for? Why is my call function not binding this to App?

Comment: You need to understand that `this.addKeyValue` is `undefined`. Before you even get to `call`. In order to call a function with `call` you need to have one first. And all you have is `undefined`.

Comment: Right, I do understand that. I was just misunderstanding the way in which the call function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But isn't that what the call function is for?

No.

`this.addKeyValue.call` will get the value of `this.addKeyValue`, which needs to be a function, then call it. The value of `this` **inside that function call** will be what you specify.

It doesn't change the value of `this` **before** you call the `call` function. You can use `bind` for that.

```
addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.addKeyValue(userInput.value);
}.bind(App));
```

Comment: Great, I understand.

Comment: extension: you can also use an arrow-function wich doesn't have an own `this` object and therefore encapsulates the `this` from the surrounding function/method: `addButton.addEventListener('click', () => { this.addKeyValue(userInput.value) });` #closure

Comment: @Thomas — Providing you are willing to [entirely sacrifice IE support](http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow).

Comment: I think `.bind(this)` is better . A class  should not be referenced itself by name

Comment: @Royi — It isn't a class

Comment: Sorry, an object.

Comment: @Quentin, it depends. I'd rather use a preprocessor to fix something like that for me. I don't like to be hold back like that by a browser. It's like a decade ago, that I manually wrote switches myself, like between `addEventListener()` and `attachEvent()` and way more stuff like that. Nowadays I use frameworks, polyfills and preprocessors to level the playing field for me; and only as far as it is required.